# Prevent the OP commenting on their own post?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Unsurprisingly, most long discussion threads under a post involve the OP — and preventing them from commenting on their own question or answer will help to reduce comments being used for discussion.

If the OP wants to discuss someone's comment, they should have the immediate option to 'take discussion to chat' instead, and be able to @reply from there.

Obviously this would change the commenting behaviour of the OP, but there may be a significant side benefit: a reduction is comments that solicit discussion from other users as we come to realise that we can't simply start a discussion thread on the post any more. All the ['correct' usages of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) would still work, as none usually require discussion:

> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Comment: Not all clarifications are... clarifications though. Sometimes you need to clarify a clarification, or even work through a problem.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek of course. And you can do that in a chat room — which is less convenient and less likely to happen, I know. But I think the question is whether it is worth the trade-off to improve the overall signal to noise ratio.

Comment: You just commented on your own question. If I understand your suggestion correctly, you don't think you should be able to do that.

Comment: If I'm reading this right... you wouldn't have been able to reply to @JourneymanGeek and I'd have to join a chat room to see if you responded to it? That's just awkward... for everyone...

Comment: @DonaldDuck this is meta, not meta meta, right?

Comment: @JonClements not if this was a post on main — but the rules are different on meta and I'm not suggesting applying this change here.

Comment: @DonaldDuck doesn't appear the OP is choosing to respond to that - how rude of him :p

Comment: @JackDouglas Similar situations can occur on main sites too. For example, you commented on your own questions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/2962) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/204716).

Comment: So what are the advantages of forcing all of the OP's comments to be moved to chat?  How does that make the site better?  Removing comments is not inherently good, especially when you're talking about removing useful comments that would have helped improve the quality of the posts they were commenting on.  If you think all comments are inherently bad and that having less is always good (first, why do you think that, but also), why do you think people other than the OP should be allowed to comment?

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, that's kinda gone against what's been conventional wisdom on comments. You can *always* comment on your own posts (even without the 50 reputation minimum) and that lets you figure out the missing parts of your posts with the help of the community.

Its useful for sometimes working through a problem (which then gets rolled into the post proper). It gives an *inband* way to do this without clicking through another room. While it can get a little noisy sometimes, the mechanics of the site result in a review by a mod at about 20 comments.

The disadvantage with moving it to a chat room is needing another click and needing to context switch between the two. Moving to chat room is kinda meant as *housekeeping* and *archiving* in practice - in addition to allowing for longform conversations. For a active question, this feels more important.

Comment: Also 1) some users don't use chat and *don't want to* use chat - certainly not for just seeing if the OP has responded to requests for clarification or asked for clarification of a clarification. Chat is somewhat more "engaged" than comments and a user might well end up being considered "interested" and pinged about things left, right and centre and treated as a kind of personal help desk (not that that doesn't happen in comments occasionally but...). 2) Moving things to chat can sometimes end up fragmenting information when people still comment after. This'd just fragment from the get-go...

Comment: Also, if you don't have 50 rep, you may also not have the 20 rep to chat.